# Error only when the app is launched in an iPhone. Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4052c00000000000)

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I am writing a program that uses data from coredata and creates a graph out of it. When I run it, it crashes with the following error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x4052c00000000000)`. The code starts from `ContentView` as follows

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var score = ""
    var reviewItem: ReviewItem
    @State private var displayNewView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: ReviewView(reviewItem: ReviewItem()), isActive: self.$displayNewView) { EmptyView() }
                Form {
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                    TextField("Score", text: $score)
                }
                .toolbar {
                    Button("add") {
                        reviewItem.saveReviewData(name: name, score: Int32(score)!)
                        self.displayNewView = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(reviewItem: ReviewItem())
    }
}
```

This is what the code for `reviewView` looks like

```
struct GradeData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var averageGrade: Int32
    var condition: String
}


struct ReviewView: View {
    
    var gradeVShours: [GradeData]
    
    init(reviewItem: ReviewItem) {
        gradeVShours = [
            GradeData(averageGrade: reviewItem.getScore(scoreType: "high"), condition: "Well"), GradeData(averageGrade: reviewItem.getScore(scoreType: "low"), condition: "Not Well")]
    }
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        Chart {
            ForEach(self.gradeVShours) { shape in
                BarMark (
                    x: .value("Total Grade", shape.averageGrade),
                    y: .value("Grade Condition", shape.condition)
                        )
                    }
                }
        } else {
            Text("Upgrade to ios version 16.0 or higher")
            }
        }
}
```

This is what the code for `ReviewItem` looks like

```
class ReviewItem: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    let coreDM: DataController = DataController.shared
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    func getListScore(scoreType: String) -> [Int32] {
        let score = coreDM.getScoreFromCoreData(scoreType: scoreType)
        return score
    }
    
    func getScore(scoreType: String) -> Int32 {
        var listScore = getListScore(scoreType: scoreType)
        let totalCount = scoreType.count
        let totalSum = listScore.reduce(0, +)
        return totalSum/Int32(totalCount)
    }
    
    
    func saveReviewData(name: String, score: Int32) {
        coreDM.saveToCoreData(name: name, score: score)
    }
}
```

This is what the code in `DataController` looks like. It is used to fetch the data from coredata. And this is where the error is thrown after the app crashes. I have noted the line where the error is thrown.

```
class DataController: ObservableObject {
static var shared = DataController()
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "StudentData")

init() {
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { description, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Core data failed to laod: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}

func getScoreFromCoreData(scoreType: String) -> [Int32] {
    //      let filter: NSPredicate
    var scoreData: [GradeTable]
    var listScore: [Int32] = []
    
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<GradeTable> = GradeTable.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    
    if scoreType == "high" {
        let filter = NSPredicate(format: "score >= %@", 85)   //Error thrown here
        fetchRequest.predicate = filter
    }
    else {
        let filter = NSPredicate(format: "score <= %@", 85)
        fetchRequest.predicate = filter
    }
    
    do {
        scoreData = try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch let error {
        print("ERROR while fetching data from db array \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
    
    for item in scoreData {
        listScore.append(item.score)
    }
    return listScore
}


func saveToCoreData(name: String, score: Int32) {
    let gradeTable = GradeTable(context: container.viewContext)
    gradeTable.uuid = UUID()
    gradeTable.name = name
    gradeTable.score = score
    
    do {
        try container.viewContext.save()
        print("Saved")
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

}

Note that `StudentData` has an entity named `GradeTable` which has attributes named `score`, `name` and `uuid` which is of data type Int32, string and UUID. The app launches fine and works well in simulator, but it crashes with the following error when I launch it in my phone.

I can't figure out what's going on. Using breakpoints didn't help much. Will you please tell me what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Okay I found the fix. Changing the datatype of the argument in the filter statement fixed it. Using `let filter = NSPredicate(format: "score >= %@", "85")` instead of `let filter = NSPredicate(format: "score >= %@", 85)` solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your DataController instance will load the persistent store in an asynchronous operation, while the view immediately creates the fetch request before the persistent store is loaded completely.

You would want to move the initialization way before the view creation, such as in the SceneDelegate.

Comment: I don't have a SceneDelegate. I was thinking one way to fix it would be by creating a function inside the view and calling the call there, but at the end of the day it didn't make any difference. Here's the link to it in github: https://github.com/uubasko/coreDataTest
If you try to run this, you'll see that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Wether it is scenedelegate, appdelegate, app. anywhere before loading your view that immediately creates a fetchrequest, you need to make sure that "container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { description, error in"
is done before. this is an asynchronous operation!

Comment: Got it. While the issue was different in this case, I'll keep it in mind for the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue, make sure to check the data type of the `filter` in Nspredicate. In my case, I was using an integer as a filter, and it was the reason behind the error. Using a string instead of an integer fixed it.

This doesn't work because the filter(85) is an integer.

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format: "score >= %@", 85)  //Error thrown here
```

This works because the filter("85") is a string.

```
let filter = NSPredicate(format: "score >= %@", "85")
```